# Hovering over an ASP session variable

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way of identifying the value of a session variable whilst single-stepping? It’s cumbersome to have to go to the Immediate window and type ?Session.Item(“Name”).

Comment: If you abstract session storage behind an object then you can expand that object to evaluate its properties.  (With the added bonus that the session dependency is abstracted from the rest of the code.)

Comment: Hi David, What does it mean to "abstract session storage"?

Comment: Build an object as a wrapper for the session dependency, so that the only references to `Session` are within that object.  Then throughout the code you would use that object instead of using `Session` directly.  (This would also increase the testability of the code.)